# Create column with aggregated value with calculation in PBI

Tags: aggregate, powerbi

Imagine you have two tables:

Table User:
`ID, Name`

Table Orders:
`ID, UserID`

I'm trying to create a new column in table `User` which should contain aggregated values of distinct count of `Order.IDs`.

Answer (score 1):

Calculated column:

```
OrderCount = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Orders[Id]))
```

Alternatively if you don't/can't have a relationship between the two tables:

```
OrderCount2 = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Orders[Id]),FILTER(Orders, Orders[UserId] = User[Id]))
```

If all you need is to display it in some visualisation, you can use `Orders[Id]` directly by setting the aggregate option to `Count (Distinct)` in `Values` under `Visualizations` side pane.